# How to Bulk import with validations and create versions using paper_trail?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, paper-trail-gem, bulk-import

I am having an array of hashes(around 20k) that I need to import but with validations and have to create the versions as well using paper_trail.

`arr = [{some_1_id: '1', some_2_id: '2', some_3_id: '3', amount: '123'}, {some_1_id: '1', some_2_id: '2', some_3_id: '3', amount: '123'}]`

I have an array of hashes like this. In this, we can expect around 20k elements that need to be saved to DB.

I have used activerecord-import but it's bypassing all of the callbacks including paper_trail callbacks.

I tried to run the callbacks like this

```
books.each do |book|
  book.run_callbacks(:save) { false }
  book.run_callbacks(:create) { false }
end
Book.import(books)
```

But it's not saving the paper_trail versions correctly.

What I did is that

```
arr.each do |a|
 valid_books = []
 book_obj = Book.new
 # validate some_1_id
 # validate some_2_id   
 # validate some_3_id
 # Some other validations
 if book_obj.valid?
   valid_books << book_obj
 end
end
 # Run call backs 
 Book.import valid_books
```

It's working as expected but performance is not good at all. its taking more than 30 secs for 10k records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> its taking more than 30 secs for 10k records.

30s is within the expected performance range for validating and creating 10k versionsed records normally (ie. `new`, `valid?`, `save` with PT callbacks). In some applications, 30s would be considered fast, especially when validations and other callbacks perform queries of their own.

I recommend putting the import process in a [background job](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) and simply asking the user to wait.

If the import is already in a background job, or a bg. job is not possible, you could explore using `activerecord-import` twice: first to create 30k `Book` records, and then to create 30k `PaperTrail::Version` records. This is an advanced technique, using private (unsupported) API of PT. To correctly instantiate the `PaperTrail::Version` objects, use `PaperTrail::Events::Create`, as `PaperTrail::RecordTrail#build_version_on_create` does. If you are successful with this technique, I'd gladly review a PR adding it to our README.